# Kernel in Jupyter Notebook crashes after update to MacOS 13.2 (22D49)

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter, macos-ventura

I can not use Python in Jupyter (in VSCode) after updating my MacOS to Ventura 13.2 (22D49). It seems to be "import pymongo" that causes the error. [image]

I tried following actions without success:

- Use ipykernel but it didn't solve the problem.
  [according to this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0TLwkje6co)
- Uninstall VSCode
- Uninstall Jupyter in VSCode

I have a MacBook Pro with M1 processor.
Happy to get some suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much of a permanent solution this is, but what worked for me was going into VS Code Extensions, search for Jupyter (which should be installed already), then at the top I chose "Switch to Pre-release version". Then you have to reload the extension and it worked for me. I hope it works for you too!

Comment: Thank you, I tried but unfortunately it didn't work for me.